# Logging response data from stream (just data not prototype functions of response object)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I stream data and when listening to data I add to my `response` object by something similar to:

```
res.write(',\n' + JSON.stringify(data.name) + ':' + JSON.stringify(data))
```

Whenever I log my `response` object it logs a big object with lots of prototype functions of response object; is there any way to log the data I have set for my reponse object whenever `end` event of stream gets triggered `stream.on('end', function(){...`?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible, beats the purpose of streaming if all data is kept in memory.

Comment: I guess you are right, but if I was not streaming, is there anyway to see the response data,(just data) not prototype functions of response?

Comment: not from the response object, the [output buffer is cleared](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L149-L161) as soon as the data is written to the socket.